# Performing a function over all pair points of a grid, R

Tags: r

I need to perform a mathematical formula over each pair points of a grid of 100*100 points, for example calculate distances of all two points and having them in a list. How I can do this in R?

Comment: Welcome to GIS.se! Could you click 'edit' and update your question with some examples of what your data look like and what you've tried already?